# How can I parse a tab separated data file and group the extracted data in Perl?

Tags: perl, graph

I am newbie to Perl. I need to parse a tab separated text file. For example:

```
From name   To name      Timestamp                 Interaction
a             b        Dec  2 06:40:23 IST 2000        comment
c             d        Dec  1 10:40:23 IST 2001          like
e             a        Dec  1 16:03:01 IST 2000         follow
b             c        Dec  2 07:50:29 IST 2002         share
a             c        Dec  2 08:50:29 IST 2001        comment
c             a        Dec 11 12:40:23 IST 2008          like
e             c        Dec  2 07:50:29 IST 2000         like
c             b        Dec 11 12:40:23 IST 2008        follow
b             a        Dec  2 08:50:29 IST 2001        share
```

After parsing I need to create groups base upon users interaction. In this example

```
a<->b
b<->a
c<->a
a<->c
b<->c
c<->b
```

for this we can create one group. and we need to display list of groups.
I need some pointers on how to parse the file and form group?

**Edit** 
Constraint->  at least 3 user required for creating group.
Interaction is nothing but some communication is done between two user. It does not matter of which communication

My Approach for solving is

1. We remove repeated interaction between users . such as "a<>b like "again if "a<>b follow" is present then we remove this row.
2. Creating 2 dimensional array which store interaction two users i.e

   ```
             To Name   a       b        c          d
   ```

   `From Name`

   ```
      a                X       <>       <>         X
      b                <>      X        <>         X
      c                <>      <>       X          X 
      d                X       <>       X          X
   ```

   X= Represent no interaction
   <>= represent interaction

In this approach we start from first row i.e "a" user check with "b". if "a" is interact with "b" then we perform reverse of i.e "b" interact with "a". same steps perform for each column.

But this approach depends on number of users. If 1000 users are present then we have to create 1000 X 1000 matrix. IS there any alternative to solve this

**I have added sample input**

```
a   c   Dec  2 06:40:23 IST 2000    comment
f   g   Dec  2 06:40:23 IST 2009    like
c   a   Dec  2 06:40:23 IST 2009    like
g   h   Dec  2 06:40:23 IST 2008    like
a   d   Dec  2 06:40:23 IST 2008    like
r   t   Dec  2 06:40:23 IST 2007    share
d   a   Dec  2 06:40:23 IST 2007    share
t   u   Dec  2 06:40:23 IST 2006    follow
a   e   Dec  2 06:40:23 IST 2006    follow
k   l   Dec  2 06:40:23 IST 2009    like
e   a   Dec  2 06:40:23 IST 2009    like
j   k   Dec  2 06:40:23 IST 2003    like
c   d   Dec  2 06:40:23 IST 2003    like
l   j   Dec  2 06:40:23 IST 2002    like
d   c   Dec  2 06:40:23 IST 2002    like
m   n   Dec  2 06:40:23 IST 2005    like
c   e   Dec  2 06:40:23 IST 2005    like
m   l   Dec  2 06:40:23 IST 2011    like
e   c   Dec  2 06:40:23 IST 2011    like
h   j   Dec  2 06:40:23 IST 2010    like
d   e   Dec  2 06:40:23 IST 2010    like
o   p   Dec  2 06:40:23 IST 2009    like
e   d   Dec  2 06:40:23 IST 2009    like
p   q   Dec  2 06:40:23 IST 2000    comment
q   p   Dec  2 06:40:23 IST 2009    like
a   p   Dec  2 06:40:23 IST 2008    like    
p   a   Dec  2 06:40:23 IST 2007    share
l   p   Dec  2 06:40:23 IST 2003    like
j   l   Dec  2 06:40:23 IST 2002    like
t   r   Dec  2 06:40:23 IST 2000    comment
r   h   Dec  2 06:40:23 IST 2009    like
j   f   Dec  2 06:40:23 IST 2008    like    
g   d   Dec  2 06:40:23 IST 2007    share
w   q   Dec  2 06:40:23 IST 2003    like
o   y   Dec  2 06:40:23 IST 2002    like
x   y   Dec  2 06:40:23 IST 2000    comment
y   x   Dec  2 06:40:23 IST 2009    like
x   z   Dec  2 06:40:23 IST 2008    like    
z   x   Dec  2 06:40:23 IST 2007    share
y   z   Dec  2 06:40:23 IST 2003    like
z   y   Dec  2 06:40:23 IST 2002    like
```

Output should be:

```
(a,c, d, e)
(x,y,z)
```

Comment: There are at least three distinct problems there (reading the file, extracting the data from it, structuring that data). Which one is giving you problems?

Comment: What have you tried? How did it not work as you expected? Where are you stuck?

Comment: @Quentin : Thanks for quick reply. I am stuck at structuring data.

Comment: @sarnold  I am new to perl. How to handle interaction of user and form group.

Comment: Are you having the problem with Perl or structuring the data itself? I can not see a detailed structure of the data that you want. You want to create 'groups base upon users interaction', interaction show in your example result. Your data has 'from' and 'to' but your output has 'a<->b' that means to me  'a' do an interaction with 'b', and 'b' does the SAME to 'a', but a->b was a comment and a<-b was a share. Doing data structures with Perl is easy (when you know how it works ;-)), but first you need to write in detail your query in order to create the right data structure to answer it.

Comment: @PabloMarin-Garcia : Interaction is nothing but some communication is done between two user. It does not matter of which communication. please let me know how we can perform groups based upon interaction

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Parsing is easy. Just a [`split /\t/`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split.html) might be enough. However, [Text::xSV](http://metacpan.org/module/Text::xSV) or [Text::CSV](http://metacpan.org/module/Text::CSV) might be better.

For the connections, you can use the [Graph](http://metacpan.org/module/Graph) module. To be able to use that module effectively, you need to understand at least the basics of [graph theory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_theory).

Note that a [strongly connected component](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strongly_connected_component) is defined as:

> A directed graph is called strongly connected if there is a path from each vertex in the graph to every other vertex. In particular, this means paths in each direction; a path from `a` to `b` and also a path from `b` to `a`.
>
> The strongly connected components of a directed graph G are its maximal strongly connected subgraphs.

However, note that if you have `a <-> b` and `b <-> c`, `a`, `b`, and `c` will form a strongly connected component meaning that is a weaker requirement than all members of a group interacted with each other in both directions.

We can still use this to reduce the search space. Once you have candidate groups, you can then check each to see if it fits your definition of a group. If a candidate group does not meet your requirements, then you can check all subsets with one fewer members. If you don't find any groups among those, you can then look at all subsets with two fewer members and so on until you hit the minimum group size limit.

The script below uses this idea. However, it very likely won't scale. I strongly suspect one might be able to put together some SQL magic but my mind is far too limited for that.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use Graph;
use Algorithm::ChooseSubsets;

use constant MIN_SIZE => 3;

my $interactions = Graph->new(
    directed => 1,
);

while (my $interaction = <DATA>) {
    last unless $interaction =~ /\S/;
    my ($from, $to) = split ' ', $interaction, 3;

    $interactions->add_edge($from, $to);
}

my @groups = map {
    is_group($interactions, $_) ? $_
                                : check_subsets($interactions, $_)
} grep @$_ >= MIN_SIZE, $interactions->strongly_connected_components;


print "Groups: \n";
print "[ @$_ ]\n" for @groups;

sub check_subsets {
    my ($graph, $candidate) = @_;

    my @groups;
    for my $size (reverse MIN_SIZE .. (@$candidate - 1)) {
        my $subsets = Algorithm::ChooseSubsets->new(
            set => $candidate,
            size => $size,
        );

        my $groups_found;
        while (my $subset = $subsets->next) {
            if (is_group($interactions, $subset)) {
                ++$groups_found;
                push @groups, $subset;
            }
        }
        last if $groups_found;
    }

    return @groups;
}

sub is_group {
    my ($graph, $candidate) = @_;

    for my $member (@$candidate) {
        for my $other (@$candidate) {
            next if $member eq $other;
            return unless $graph->has_edge($member, $other);
            return unless $graph->has_edge($other, $member);
        }
    }

    return 1;
}

__DATA__
a   c   Dec  2 06:40:23 IST 2000    comment
f   g   Dec  2 06:40:23 IST 2009    like
c   a   Dec  2 06:40:23 IST 2009    like
g   h   Dec  2 06:40:23 IST 2008    like
a   d   Dec  2 06:40:23 IST 2008    like
r   t   Dec  2 06:40:23 IST 2007    share
d   a   Dec  2 06:40:23 IST 2007    share
t   u   Dec  2 06:40:23 IST 2006    follow
a   e   Dec  2 06:40:23 IST 2006    follow
k   l   Dec  2 06:40:23 IST 2009    like
e   a   Dec  2 06:40:23 IST 2009    like
j   k   Dec  2 06:40:23 IST 2003    like
c   d   Dec  2 06:40:23 IST 2003    like
l   j   Dec  2 06:40:23 IST 2002    like
d   c   Dec  2 06:40:23 IST 2002    like
m   n   Dec  2 06:40:23 IST 2005    like
c   e   Dec  2 06:40:23 IST 2005    like
m   l   Dec  2 06:40:23 IST 2011    like
e   c   Dec  2 06:40:23 IST 2011    like
h   j   Dec  2 06:40:23 IST 2010    like
d   e   Dec  2 06:40:23 IST 2010    like
o   p   Dec  2 06:40:23 IST 2009    like
e   d   Dec  2 06:40:23 IST 2009    like
p   q   Dec  2 06:40:23 IST 2000    comment
q   p   Dec  2 06:40:23 IST 2009    like
a   p   Dec  2 06:40:23 IST 2008    like
p   a   Dec  2 06:40:23 IST 2007    share
l   p   Dec  2 06:40:23 IST 2003    like
j   l   Dec  2 06:40:23 IST 2002    like
t   r   Dec  2 06:40:23 IST 2000    comment
r   h   Dec  2 06:40:23 IST 2009    like
j   f   Dec  2 06:40:23 IST 2008    like
g   d   Dec  2 06:40:23 IST 2007    share
w   q   Dec  2 06:40:23 IST 2003    like
o   y   Dec  2 06:40:23 IST 2002    like
x   y   Dec  2 06:40:23 IST 2000    comment
y   x   Dec  2 06:40:23 IST 2009    like
x   z   Dec  2 06:40:23 IST 2008    like
z   x   Dec  2 06:40:23 IST 2007    share
y   z   Dec  2 06:40:23 IST 2003    like
z   y   Dec  2 06:40:23 IST 2002    like
```

Output:

```
Groups:
[ y z x ]
[ e d a c ]
```

Comment: Unur :  Thanks for some pointers. But how can we represent logically using graph. I am new to graph, and perl.

Comment: Unur : Thanks for example. I will try it. Criteria for creating groups "Every user in the group must have bidirectional Interactions with all other users in that group(atleast 3 user required to form group). i.e if interaction happen between a->b ; b ->a ; a -> c; c->a; c->b; b->c then we can create group as (a,b,c).

Comment: In your output it display (s, q). But in your input files there is interaction between s to q not from q to s. and atleast 3 user required to form group.

Comment: Sorry, I should have to mention "Edit" in question. Thanks for suggestion , I will look into perl graph for implementation.

Comment: Apologies for incomplete requirement ,furthermore  I am newbie to perl . It would be great help for me, if you provide me any approach for directed graph(bidirection interaction between users). Your efforts would be appreciated.

Comment: I really appreciate your help and  patience:) Your solution is working for most of the cases.I have added sample input where your code dont give required output. I am working on your solution to get it work.Thanks a lot.

Comment: Thank you very much. Its working as mention. You save my lots of time. you are genius.

Comment: Is it possible to print Groups in which all the interactions have been within N years of each other.(N as number of years).

Comment: @Raje Yes, it is possible. However, you'll need to define *within N years of each other* better. Then you can do some additional work during parsing to store the information, and figure out whether the additional criteria should be taken into account when building the graph, or after the list of groups has been determined. If you run into difficulties, post a new question with a detailed specification. But, in the final analysis, keep in mind that SO is not a free outsourcing agency.